# How many ways are there to pair up $10$ girls and $11$ boys ($1$ boy & $1$ girl) such that one of the pairs has $2$ boys and $1$ girl?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to pair up $10$ girls and $11$ boys ($1$ boy & $1$ girl) such that one of the pairs has $2$ boys and $1$ girl?
Is the answer to this question same as $10$ girls & $10$ boys pairing? 
I am confused about this..
My answer that I came up with :
$$C(11,2) \cdot (10) \cdot 9!$$ 
Hence, $$C(11,2) \cdot 10!$$ 
Since ordering of which $2$ boys I choose does not matter, I used combination instead of permutation.
Is this the correct answer?

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: You're missing a whole bunch of spaces there, in between the words.